# I'm trying to create a function to delete data from the database by Python(PyQt5)

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a function to delete Mysql data from a tableWidget but I'm not getting it, could someone help me?

This is my code:

```
banco = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="controle_teste"
)
class telaprocurar(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,*args,**argvs):
        super(telaprocurar,self).__init__(*args,**argvs)
        self.ui = Ui_procurar()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pesquisar)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.gerarpdf)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.can)
        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.dell)


    def pegaselecaodobanco(self):
        return self.ui.tableWidget.currentRow()
    def pegaselecaodatabela(self):
        valor = self.ui.tableWidget.item(self.pegaselecaodobanco(),0)
        return valor.text()

    def dell(self):

        try:
            cursor = banco.cursor()
            id = self.pegaselecaodatabela()
            print(id)
            cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM beneficio WHERE id = {id} ")
            QMessageBox.information(QMessageBox(), "SUCESSO", "DADOS EXCLUIDOS COM SUCESSO!!!")

        except:
            QMessageBox.warning(QMessageBox(),"ERRO", "OCORREU UM ERRO, TENTE NOVAMENTE")
```

it finds the ID in the bank but does not delete.I'm trying to create a function to delete Mysql data from a tableWidget but I'm not getting it, could someone help me?

it finds the ID in the bank but does not delete.
what appears: built-in function id

Comment: The code doesn't commit the database changes, and it doesn't update the table-widget.

Comment: I got it with the tip you gave me thanks @ekhumoro